# How to setup IIS Express from a script the way Visual Studio does it?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-express, appcmd

When we configure a web application to run in IIS Express there are certain things VS does, like:

1. Creating the application host configuration file in the IISExpress subfolder of the user documents folder.
2. Creating a dedicated site section for each web application in the solution, including ours.

Maybe more things are done, which I am unaware of.

I would like to replicate the same process from a script, so that running the web application from the script would be equivalent to running it from VS. Including for the very first time.

Right now I start IISExpress with the `/port` and `/path` flags, because this is how I used to run Cassini. However, Cassini supported an additional flag - `/vpath`. They removed it from IISExpress, meaning I have to use another set of flags - `/config`, `/site`, `/siteid`. But I suspect it must be done in conjunction with the `Appcmd.exe` utility.

This second approach is still something I haven't managed to master. So, my question is this - suppose I am given the port, path and vpath of a web application (i.e. no need to read them from the web application's csproj file, like VS does). What command sets up the right application host configuration file and how do I run IISExpress to take advantage of it?